# Can you give an examples of non commutative non C*algebras?

Tags: c-star-algebras, banach-algebras, gelfand-representation

Are there examples apart from $B(X)$ where $X$ is not a Hilbert space and not finite dimensional. Do they have a characterization or representation?

Comment: To be clear, you want examples of Banach algebras?

Comment: Yes. But they should be non commutative and non C*.

Comment: How about $M_2(A)$ where $A$ is a commutative example (like the disc algebra)?

Comment: Could you please specify what $M_2(A)$ stands for?

Comment: @WilsonGeorge: $M_2(A)$ is the ring of $2\times 2$ matrices with entries from $A$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be the algebra of all $2\times2$ matrices over $\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$) of the form
$$\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
0 & c
\end{bmatrix} $$
Then $A$ is a Banach algebra, which is noncommutative, and is not a $C^*$-algebra.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Awygan. But I have mentioned that I require an example apart from B(X), where X is a Hilbert space or finite dimensional.

Comment: You added that requirement after my post was made.  If you want a sufficient answer, you should ask a sufficient question.  I'm guessing you also want a $^*$-algebra?

Comment: I am sorry about that. No, * algebra is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If a complex finite dimensional algebra is a C^* algebra, then it is isomorphic to a direct product of matrix algebras. So any algebra which is not of this form gives you an example.

Comment: Notice that every finite dimensional complex algebra has a Banach norm.